# how to check and compare the file names that are inside a folder (Datalake) using ADF

Tags: azure, file, azure-data-factory

My requirement is to compare the files names in the Datalake folder with the filenames in the .CSV File and if the filenames are matching then I want to copy these files and if filenames are not matching then I want to store these file names in a .CSV file in the datalake.

Kindly Help.

Comment: Do you want to save all the filenames in a new csv file if they are not matching?

Comment: Yes, Exactly...

Comment: So, filenames from both folder and the csv file which are not matching have to be included in this new csv file? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Lets say folder has files as `s1.csv, s2.csv and s3.csv` and csv file has filenames `s1.csv, s2.csv and s10.csv`. What are all the files names that you expect to store in the new csv file?

Comment: I want s3.csv  to be stored in the new csv file and I want s1.csv , s2.csv to be copied to another location in the ADLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the requirement in the following way using 3 steps i.e., get filenames from csv file and ADLS folder, filter the matching and unmatched file names (from folder) and finally do respective copy operations.

**Step-1**:

- I used `get metadata` activity to get the list of filenames from ADLS folder (*sample1.csv, sample2.csv, sample3.csv, sample4.csv*). Create dataset pointing to your folder and use `child items` as field list.

[image]

- And `look up` to get the filenames (*sample1.csv, sample2.csv, sample5.csv, sample6.csv*) from the csv file.

[image]

**Step-2**

- Now using filter activity, get the matching file names. I used the following as my items and filter condition to get matching filenames:

```
items- @activity('list of files in folder').output.childItems
condition- @contains(string(activity('filenames present in csv').output.value),item().name)
```

[image]

- To get the unmatched filenames from the ADLS folder, I used the following items and filter condition:

```
items- @activity('list of files in folder').output.childItems
condition- @not(contains(string(activity('filenames present in csv').output.value),item().name))
```

[image]

**Step-3:**

- Now, use for each activity to copy each file to another location. I used the items value in 1st for each as `@activity('getting matching files').output.Value`. Inside this, I have configured a copy activity to copy the current for each item (i.e., filename).
- I have created a parameter in [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a597U.png) called `filename`. I passed its value (@item().name) from copy data source settings as shown below.

[image]

- Now for unmatched filenames from folder, I used for each and append variable to create an array of filenames like `["sample3.csv", "sample4.csv"]`. The items value in for each is `@activity('getting unmatched files').output.Value`.
- Inside for each, I used `append variable` with value as `@item().name`.

[image]

- Now, we have to create a new csv file with all the unmatched filenames from folder. Use copy data activity, take a [sample csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhJ84.png) (with some content. This content doesnot matter, we just need a file to use as source).
- Now add an additional column, called filenames with dynamic content value as below. (Make sure in pipeline JSON the filenames value is same as in [this reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olx3F.png) )

```
@join(variables('filenames'),'
')

#the values will be joined using newline(\n). 
#Using \n directly in dynamic content would not work as it will be taken as \\n. 
#So change it in pipeline json as in above reference image.
```

[image]

- Configure the sink as following. Select the path, filename and make sure to select quote character as `no quote character`.

[image]

**Output:**

- When I run the pipeline, it would generate the required output. The matched and copied files are generated as below:

[image]

- The unmatched filenames written to csv files will be as shown below:

[image]