# Requiremet of Error logging mail(mail should contain all the missing file details). in the ADF flow

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

the reqirement is simple , i have a folder having 4 txt files(1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt) . the Flow is controlled by a parameter called **all or some** which is of string type.
[image: This is the adf pipeline, with the activities]

If i select all in the parameter, all 4 file should be processed. the requirement starts here >>

1. IF any file is missing from the folder(for ex **2.txt and 3.txt** is not present and i selected **ALL** in the parameter) , i need a mail saying file is 2.txt and 3.txt is missing.
2. If i select some in the parameter, for ex **1.txt and 4.txt** and if any of the file is missing 1.txt and 4.txt is missing(for example 1.txt is missing) , i need a mail with the missing file name(i.e 1.txt in our case).

Comment: What is the requirement? Is this to find the missing files? or to send the mail from ADF pipeline?

Comment: Hi Aswin,both , but sending mail is not of much preference , as if i can capture missing file details in one variable or something , i can call that variable in the email Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> capture missing file details in one variable

I tried to repro this capturing missing files using azure data factory. Below is the approach.

- Take a parameter of **array** type in the pipeline. During runtime, you can give the list of file names in a folder to be processed in this array parameter.
  [image]
- Take a **get metadata** activity and add a dataset in the activity. Click **+New** in the field list and select **child items** as an argument.

[image]

- Take a filter activity and give the array parameter value in items and write the condition to filter the missing files in condition box

**item:**
`@pipeline().parameters.AllorSome`

**condition:**
`@not(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),item()))`

- I tried to run this pipeline. During run time, four file names are given to the array parameter.
  [image]
- Get Metadata activity output has three file names.

[image]

- Parameter has 4 filenames and Get meta data activity has 3 filenames. Missing file names are to be filtered out.
- **Output of filter activity:**

[image]

- Use this output and send it in email.
- Refer the  **MS document**  on  [How to send email - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email)  for sending email.

Comment: hey aswin , thank you, just for simplicity i used , 4 files , that requirement is for 12-16 files , generally we dont keep all the file names , we Give "ALL"  as parameter value , by default ,the parameter value goes to the switch statement , where we have diferent Dataflow running for all the different types of files( 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt )

Comment: 2 ) there is already a Filter Activity i am using to filter the Text file from the folder and then to use the filter activity result to Another Filter Activity as u show.

the Files are present in a Folder ,,which is in SFTP folder

Comment: hey aswin , thank you, just for simplicity i used , 4 files , that requirement is for 12-16 files , generally we dont keep all the file names , we Give "ALL" as parameter value , by default ,the parameter value goes to the switch statement , where we have diferent Dataflow running for all the different types of files( 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt )

i am trying to use the below in Filter items :@array(if(equals(pipeline().parametrs.AllorSome,string(["1.txt","2.txt",........,"5.txt"]),pipeline().parametrs.AllorSome)
error because  i have the file name  as 1*.txt,2*.txt,3*.txt * is Date concat.

Comment: that doesnt give any error , thankyou, but that doest solve , because as i am trying to compare it with a parameter and the parameter value passed is All so the output i am getting is "All" only

Comment: when Values is passed as all , right , the value is passed to a Switch statement , where Seperate Dataflow Activities are available for the 4 files as per the business need , this get s processed

Comment: Let us continue our discussion in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250789/74967032)

Comment: yeah ashwin , so i am storing it in a Variable as default values

Comment: Try using If activity and check if parameter is "All"; in true section of if activity, Add the similar filter activity Enter the item value as variable output and for false section, Give the above (answer) approach.

Comment: Thank you for you help, aswin , is there any way , to show non common values between 2 variables of Array type? for example Var1["1.txt","2.txt","3.txt","4.txt"] and var2["4.txt","3.txt"]  

answer :: ["1.tst","2.txt"] which i will store in Another Variable var3

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486349/how-to-check-and-compare-the-file-names-that-are-inside-a-folder-datalake-usin). If you find any difficulties in this approach, create another new Question in Stack overflow on that. So, Community members will help there :)